# How to set the type of a manually opened keyboard (without a TextField)

Tags: flutter, dart

My Flutter app has a view similar to a text terminal.  It uses a Focus widget to respond to keyboard input without use of a TextField or a similar widget.  It works well on desktop platforms, but I'm having trouble showing the correct type of keyboard on Android.

I used `SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.show");` to show a keyboard, but it seems to default to an input type that only allows numbers to be entered.  How do I set it to a normal text or multiline keyboard type?